# Angular UI modal not showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a modal that pops up when the user clicks on an element created like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="task in tasks | filter:{Status: 0}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger" ng-click="getTask(task)">
```

This is the getTask function:

```
    $scope.getTask = function (task) {
        taskService.getTask(task.Id)
            .then(task => {
                var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    animation: true,
                    templateUrl: "Content/partials/TaskModal.html",
                    controller: "taskModalController",
                    resolve: {
                        task: function () {
                            return task
                        }
                    }
                });

                modalInstance.result.then(task => {
                    if (task)
                        updateTask(task); 
                });
            })
    };
```

And the template is just a div with a form in it.

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Edit Task</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form name="EditTask" ng-submit="saveTask()" class="form-inline mb-5">
            <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                <label for="Assignee">Assignee</label>
                <input type="text" name="Assignee" class="form-control" required ng-model="EditTask.Assignee" ng-minlength="5" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                <label for="Assignment">Assignment</label>
                <input type="text" name="Assignment" class="form-control" ng-model="EditTask.Assignment" required ng-minlength="5" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                <input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"
                       ng-disabled="EditTask.$invalid" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

When clicking on the element the modal is actually created, however it's completely invisible. Buttons can be clicked and the pointer changes when hovering over them and inspecting the file shows that the information is passed correctly.

What am I missing here that's preventing me from showing this modal?

Edit:

In the `head` I have the CSS links:

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

And at the bottom of the body the scripts:

```
<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/directives.js"></script>
```

Comment: Let's see your script and css references for ui-bootstrap.

Comment: @Lex edited the post to include the references.

Comment: I'm not sure if the ui-bootstrap stuff works with bootstrap 4.x. Maybe try referencing a 3.x version of the bootstrap css?